# Passing function as variable make it fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm passing jQuery UI format date function as parameter somewhere in my code.

However it's failing with error `Cannot read property 'dayNamesShort' of undefined`.

To reproduces :

```
jQuery.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date()); // works

var formatDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate;
formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date() ); // does not works
```

I'm guessing this is due to some use of `this` within the jQuery method, but I don't know how to fix.

Here's a complete reproductible snippet:

```js
(function($){
  $(function(){
    console.log(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date() ));
    
    var formatDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate;
    console.log(formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date() ));  

  });  
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[edit] thanks to @T.J Crowder comments and answers in the duplicate question, here's a set of possible answers :

```js
(function($){
  $(function(){
    console.log(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date() ));
    
    // wrapping in a new function
    var formatDate = function(format, date, options){ 
      return jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(format, date, options);
    };
    console.log("1:", formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date() ));

    // preserving the this context within jquery code
    var formatDate2 = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate.bind(jQuery.datepicker);
   
    console.log("2:",formatDate2( "yy-mm-dd", new Date() ));

    // applying this (less practical though)
    var formatDate3 = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate;
   
    console.log("3:",formatDate3.apply(jQuery.datepicker, [ "yy-mm-dd", new Date() ]));

  });  
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `var formatDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate` => `var formatDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate.bind(jQuery.datepicker);` (or `var formatDate = date => jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(date);` in a modern JavaScript environment). See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, bind does not solves the problem : https://codepen.io/stevebeauge/pen/GzajxJ?editors=1011. Or did I miss something ?

Comment: There's something *else* wrong with the codepen. Immediately after commenting I used "edit" to add `.bind(jQuery.datepicker)` to your Stack Snippet and it fixed the problem. (Naturally I didn't save the edit.) (I like to double-check these things, since of course sometime one misses a subtlety.)

Comment: nevermind, I wrote datApicker instead of datEpicker. anyways, thanks for the help

Comment: LOL, and here I was about to post this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqobyV?editors=1111 Glad that helped!